# How to prevent favicon href from changing by triggering onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, favicon

We have a favicon on page head (`<link rel="...">`).

If someone changes the icon dynamically via Javascript, is there a way to catch this event? (In order to prevent the favicon from changing?)

Comment: What's your goal here, to prevent the favicon from being changed on the client side? Or to detect when the favicon is changed?

Comment: I'd suggest using jQuery/Angular to watch the element.